# [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 154: Health: not ready from Kubernetes calico node

Tags: kubernetes, calico

Today I found my pod could not access the internet, then I trace the calico node and found log like this:

```
2023-10-03 13:45:41.724 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:45:41.725 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:45:41.725 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 154: Health: not ready
2023-10-03 13:45:49.150 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:45:49.150 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:45:49.256 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:45:49.256 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:45:49.256 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 154: Health: not ready
2023-10-03 13:45:59.150 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:45:59.150 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:45:59.277 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:45:59.277 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:45:59.277 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 154: Health: not ready
2023-10-03 13:46:09.149 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:46:09.149 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:46:09.257 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:46:09.257 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:46:09.257 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 154: Health: not ready
2023-10-03 13:46:19.148 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:46:19.148 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:46:19.263 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="int_dataplane"
2023-10-03 13:46:19.263 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 188: Reporter is not ready. name="async_calc_graph"
2023-10-03 13:46:19.263 [WARNING][66] felix/health.go 154: Health: not ready
```

I have already searching from internet and found someone told that maybe the ip detect failed issue, so I tried to tweak the ip detect strategy `IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD` like this:

```
        - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_NODE_SELECTOR
          value: all()
        - name: CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND
          value: bird
        - name: IP
          value: autodetect
        - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
          value: "interface=eth0"
```

still did not fixed this issue. Am I missing something?What should I do do fixed this issue? the Kubernetes cluster version is 1.26. the calico version is `image: docker.io/calico/cni:v3.20.0`. the part of host ifconfig command look like this:

```
califb5dc430c6b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1480
        inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.217.209  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.29.223.255
        inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe29:1d88  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:16:3e:29:1d:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19770425848  bytes 16068143590245 (14.6 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11665292280  bytes 9569887384561 (8.7 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15831034437  bytes 3182325844612 (2.8 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15831034437  bytes 3182325844612 (2.8 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tunl0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1480
        inet 10.97.196.192  netmask 255.255.255.255
        tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I also tried to tweak like this:

```
- name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
  value: can-reach=223.5.5.5
```

still could not fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this issue on github](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/4605) that reports the same error as you. Going through the responses in that thread the fixes that worked for other people are:

- Make sure you're using the latest version of Calico
- Upgrade your k8s platform (docker, kind, etc)
- Check that your pods/nodes have enough CPU

If those suggestions don't work for you, you'd get more calico-specific visibility in the [Project Calico Slack Community](https://slack.projectcalico.org/).